# noexcept of a function returning a class having throwing destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, noexcept

In the following code, I thought that the assertion shouldn't fire but it does.

```
struct A
{
  ~A() noexcept(false);
};

A f() noexcept;

int main()
{
  static_assert(noexcept(f()), "f must be noexcept");
}
```

The function `f()` is noexcept obviously, but `noexcept(f())` is evaluated to false. (in both of gcc and clang)

Am i missing something or is it a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `noexcept` operator on an expression `e` tells you whether the *set of potential exceptions* of the expression is empty. This set contains the potential exceptions of the destructor, as per [except.spec]/(13.2):

> If `e` implicitly invokes one or more functions (such as an overloaded operator, an allocation function in a new-expression, or **a destructor if e is a full-expression (1.9)**), *S* is the union of: [...]  the sets of types in the exception specifications of all such functions

Comment: Is this in a C++17 draft? I can't find your passge in the C++14 standard.

Comment: @Simple: Yes, it's from head. Good question, I don't know when this last changed.

Comment: @Simple: Looks like the wording was added as part of the resolution of [CWG 1992](http://wg21.link/cwg1992), which was accepted as a Defect Report at the February 2016 meeting. Being a defect means that the issue may be fixed retroactively for all previous revisions, though, since it captures essentially what *should* always have been meant.

Comment: The version of the standard doesn't matter; `noexcept` has always included everything explicitly or implicitly called by an expression.